# Can I leave pre-primed wood siding unpainted during winter?

Tags: wood, paint, siding, primer, winter

Unfortunately, I recently brushed against the corner of my house as I was pulling through our *very* narrow driveway, which pulled off a corner piece of trim as well as damaging two pieces of wooden siding.

I'm getting things repaired (happening right now, actually), but I live in a climate where it is quite cold. It's about 25F today and will be in the 20s a substantial part of next week (and probably further into the winter months). This means it's not really possible to paint, as the exterior paint I have requires a minimum temperature of 35-45F.

The replacement siding is pre-primed, but the trim wood is not. The trim sections are small, however, and the contractor is painting them in their heated trailer so that they will be protected. My concern is with the larger pre-primed siding pieces.

1. Is it acceptable to leave these pieces unpainted and uncovered over the winter, or should I plan to tape up a tarp or something equivalent over the two pieces of siding?
2. If I do leave them uncovered, what steps do I need to take when painting in the spring? I've seen suggestions that I should simply clean and lightly sand the siding before applying paint, as well as cleaning / sanding and then applying an oil-based primer before applying latex paint.

Comment: You haven't told us what the siding _is_. "Wood" can mean many things.

Comment: I wish I could give more details beyond wood, but this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: @TARehman, please ask your supplier or contractor, what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Primers aren't designed to shed water like exterior paints are.

If possible, hang a tarp from a gutter, get some heat going and put a quick coat of paint on it.

There is a chance that the material might deteriorate somewhat throughout the winter, how much is dependent on what type of weather it is exposed to.

Comment: If I'm not in a position to actually heat and paint, would it be wise to at least cover it with a tarp or something?

Comment: Depending on how it is covered, if it is covered tightly and has limited air flow it might trap moisture and get moldy. How big of an area are you talking about, how many sq ft of siding? I would hate to replace siding only to have it get ruined by the weather.

Comment: @TARehman Also, what type of siding? Lap siding? What material?

Comment: Not too experienced about siding, but it's wood and each piece overlaps the top of the next piece. It's just two pieces, they're 11 foot long and about 10 inches high. The house is 100 years old as of last year.

Answer (score 2):

Paint the siding indoors and then install it.

Then, in the spring, you just wash off any dirt, patch nail holes, and paint till your heart's content.

Comment: That would work but the OP says the siding was already being installed.

Comment: @matt. Yeah, gotta love it when contractors take shortcuts just because the client doesn't know better.